# Any ideas on creating a custom button for policy acknowledgement?

Tags: javascript, force.com, button

A URL field will link to externally hosted policy documentation that users must review and acknowledge once per year.

The Salesforce.com system needs to track who has acknowledged the policy and when.

Without an integration with this external system, could a custom button with javascript be implemented to update some fields?

Is there a better way of handling this?

Answer (score 2):

You could have a visualforce page which has the policy document as an apex:frame and has a button on it which says Acknowldege. On the button click you can either use the Ajax toolkit to update fields using JavaScript or equally since you now have a visualforce page you could write a little action method on a controller to update the fields.

This solution to another question may help you with the actual implementation, although in this case it would be a VF commandButton rather than a detail button.

[How can I update a field with a custom button?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2231/how-can-i-update-a-field-with-a-custom-button/2235#2235)

Answer (score 1):

"Without integration to external system"

Presumably you mean you don't want to store any of the external system data in SFDC, but just want to display some external content. .

Ok, you have options:

Custom Web Tab. This is a bit of overkill, but certainly, you could embed an external URL in a tab and have the external web page display as if it is appearing in SFDC. Maybe not the best idea in this instance.

Another option could be visualforce with an apex:iFrame component in it. This is maybe a better idea. You could either have that visualforce page render on its own. It then wouldn't be impossible to have the page linked to whatever data in SFDC that is going to store the acknowledgement.

I think there are options for custom buttons as well, but that's not something I've dabbled a lot in. But pretty easy to do where the button just renders in a second browser window. More difficult, however, is to store the response.

IMO, the Visuaforce option is going to be the most simple to implement and fits this requirement best.