# Parsing return from Salesforce's connection.js library

Tags: javascript

I used [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2231/how-can-i-update-a-field-with-a-custom-button) to create a button which sets a checkbox field on the Case object (see below).  I wish to add simple error handling by examining the return value "result".  What's a simple way to parse `result` for `success:'true'` or `success:'false'`?

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")} 
var c = new sforce.SObject("Case"); 
c.id ="{!Case.Id}"; 

c.User_Request_To_Close__c = true; 
result = sforce.connection.update([c]); 
alert("Request sent with result="+result);
```

Note: When this succeeds the alert shows:

> `result={id:'salesforce ID', success:'true',}`

When this fails the alert shows:

> `result={errors:{blah blah blah}, id:null, success:'false',}`

I tried using JSON.parse(result) as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript) 
but it barfed with the error "JSON Parse error: Expected '}'"  I'm not entirely sure why except there seems to be a dangling "," at the end of the return.

Insights appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Ajax Toolkit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/Content/sforce_api_ajax_introducing.htm) has some basic error handling in its [documentation examples](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/Content/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples.htm) as well as in the [error handling section](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/Content/sforce_api_ajax_errors.htm) of the docs, they are minimal but worth a look.

A basic mechanism for error handling can look like this, no need to use the `JSON.parse()` function if you don't want to:

```
// execute the update operation
var response = sforce.connection.update([c]);

if (response[0].getBoolean('success')) {
    alert('success!');
    // do other successful things

} else {
    alert('An error occurred updating this record:\n\n' + response[0].errors.message);
}
```

Comment: Yep, that works!  The [samples](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/Content/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples.htm) is a useful page.  connection.js source indicates the update() method could also take callbacks for errors as well but that seemed like overkill...